# How to get body object parameters in php curl api passed from post request in reactjs using react query?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, fetch-api, php-curl, react-query

Without using fetch api and sending data to db how we can request the body object parameters  in php curl using react query

e.g sample request -
`api.example.com/plans`

body-

```
            {
             'mobile_no': $curlopt_fields
             }
```